# How to stub everything on an object using mocha

Tags: ruby, testing, ruby-mocha

How to stub out all the methods on an object using mocha ?

I tried

1. `object.stubs(:everything)`
2. `stub_everything('class_name')`

Both of the above ways are not working.

Comment: As @dombesz says, version 2 should work. Can you explain why you think it isn't working? Perhaps you expect it to work differently?

Comment: I believe he is trying to do what I want to do, i.e. something to the effect of `RestClient.expect.any_method.never` instead of having to write `RestClient.expect(:get).never; RestClient.expect(:post).never; RestClient.expect(:put).never; RestClient.expect(:delete).never`. There doesn't seem to be a way.

Answer (score 6):

The second method should work. See the [Mocha Api](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/API.html#M000004)

```
def test_product
  product = stub_everything('ipod_product', :price => 100)
  assert_nil product.manufacturer
  assert_nil product.any_old_method
  assert_equal 100, product.price
end
```